# Как я могу обновить данные в ячейке Excel

Tags: java, excel

В Excel.xls файле у меня есть формула. Каждый раз обращаясь к ячейке, в которой она лежит, я получаю один и тот же ответ. В самом xls я использовал клавишу F9 для перерасчета, но хочу сделать это в коде, но на просторах интернета я не нашел решения. Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо!

Comment: VBA ? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato вы хотите добавить тригер при запуске, чтобы он обновлял файл?

Comment: Я не увидел метку Java. Для меня вопрос прозвучал абстрактно, вот я и посоветовал использовать VBA -_- Сорян. По Java я не шарю.